# FILETIME on x64

Tags: c#, .net, c++, winapi, interop

I'm using this FILETIME structure for interop:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct FILETIME
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int dwLowDateTime;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int dwHighDateTime;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long QuadDateTime;
}
```

It seems to work on x86(can't test right now), but will it work on x64. I'm using quadpart to convert between DateTime and FILETIME.

Comment: When working with operating system structures, you will save yourself a lot of confusion if you use `Int32` and `Int64` rather than `int` and `long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work on x64 but may not work on other processor architectures (for example IA64, if you care about it).

In win32 FILETIME is 4-byte aligned.  If you run on an architecture that requires 64-bit `long` to be 8-byte aligned then access to the QuadDataTime field may cause an exception.

Comment: Why would access to the 64 bit overlay cause an exception?

Comment: It can cause alignment fault if the pointer is not 8-byte aligned and the architecture requires alignment.  See the MSDN documentation for FILETIME which explicitly warns about casting pointer to FILETIME to __int64*.

Answer (score 2):

That should be fine. The size of data types is fixed in .NET regardless of the underlying architecture (x86 or x64). Your structure will always be 8 bytes in size.